# algorithmic, text after algorithm appears before it

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

I am using `algorithmic` package. I have description of an algorithm in `\begin{algorithm} ... \end{algorithm}`, and I have text before it. However, the text appears after algorithm in the pdf. Why does it happen? and how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: This is because `algorithm` is a floating environment.  A good reference is [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat).

Comment: This sounds like an issue to do with floating environments. Have a look at [questions concerning floats](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+keep+a+float+close)

Comment: is there package for writing algorithms which is not a floating environment?

Comment: I solved it by putting `[H]` after `\begin{algorithm}`